App memory (documents & data) increases every single call to iCloud?
i have an issue where my application's 'documents & data' increases every call to icloud for my "countries" objects. I have simplified the entire process down to the block of code below and it still causes the memory to grow. As there are no view models I dont think there is a memory leak or retain cycle. Using the ".task{}" modifier should cancel the task when i close the app but I let the function finish and this still happens.
Note this is an app i am just testing launching from Xcode 15.3 on my iPhone. The memory continues to grow from 22MB and will not stop until you delete the app from the phone ie. +600MB and grows by about 24.9MB each call to iCloud and gets 18 "countries" record from iCloud.
Does anyone have any suggestions or has come up against this issue before?
 import SwiftUI
 import CloudKit

 @main
 struct MyApp: App {
     
     var body: some Scene {
         WindowGroup {
             Text("Help me please")
                 .task {
                     await temporaryTestFunction()
                 }
         }
     }
     
     func temporaryTestFunction() async {
         
         let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
         let query = CKQuery(recordType: Constants.recordTypes.countries, predicate: predicate)
         let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
         
         do {
             /// THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE THAT CAUSES MEMORY TO GROW?
             let (response, cursorReturned) = try await privateDatabase.records(matching: query)  
             print("response.count = \(response.count)")
            
         } catch let error {
         }
     }
 }

I have tested in instruments and the memory does not seem to be retained anywhere once the process finishes.

SOLVED: CKAsset files are kept in the File Manager for use by the app. You can manually clear these out after you have used the CKAsset by the 'asset.fileURL' and then removing it from the File Manager.
